# Sfx library meta data for batch uploading 

Tags: sfx, library, metadata

What meta data information should I have embedded in each audio file to make batch uploading my sound library to multiple distribution sites easier?

Pond5
Audiomicro
Audiojungle
Audio Sparx

Comment: Do you mean what metadata categories or what metadata formats/wrappers?  It's actually two entirely different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Nevis,

I'm not sure if you mean organizing your metadata for your own benefit (to make uploading easier), or for the website's benefit (so the websites can read the metadata).

If you're thinking about organizing your metadata so it will be prepared to fit with every website out there, I'm sorry to say that there's no standard method of categorization.  Every website has their own sound effect categories.  Some need just 'description'.  Others need 'genre,' 'category,' etc.  In my experience I've had to re-categorize my library for every website I partner with.

If, on the other hand, you mean categorizing you library so that the websites can take advantage of embedded Soundminer metadata, you're similarly out of luck.  Only one website I know of reads metadata in their ingestion process, and that is Sounddogs.com.  The rest of them read your descriptions and categories via a combination of Excel sheets or tab-delimited files.  Or, like Audio Sparx, multi webpage manual entry (shudder).

I hope I've answered your question, if I can expand on anything, let me know.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Hi, I mean what metadata categories do I need to include?  Thanks for helping me clarify that.
For example  AudioSparx have the following categories
Sound Category > Subcategory
    Household Sound Effects
       Light switch sound effects
Extended Properties
  Duration: 0:01   Tempo:
   Arrangement:
   Vocal Mix: Undetermined
   Language:

If I add this information as metadata within the audio file and upload to another distribution site, say Audio Jungle am I correct in thinking I'll only ever have to add this information once?